# Howto start a JGraph based tool

Tags: java, installation

I have a minor setup problem due to the Swing component JGraph. I download the zip file from the [website](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraphdownload.html). Well, it contains all the sources. - But I miss a jar in order to use it as a library.

I'm sure this is not intended. So I wonder how to get a start with it (run the examples).

Do I have to compile it and generate the jar on my own? If somebody has an idea how I can utilize this library as it is supposed to be, that'd be great. It's a little to bare for me.

Best,
wishi

Comment: Usually it will come with its own jars. ... and on review of the download, yours does just this. Have you looked in the libs folder of your downloaded zip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a jgraph.jar in the /lib directory.  Is that the one you're missing?

It doesn't appear to have any dependency JARs.  You're on your own there.

Comment: jepp, not one my brighter moments here ;) Sorry. Thank you! ;)

Comment: No worries; we all do it from time to time.  Sometimes you just need another pair of eyes.